# Erro de função preProcess não encontrada

Tags: r, preprocessador

Instalei o pacote Caret para executar a função preProcess, mas apresenta erro de que não foi localizada. o que pode ser?

Comment: Guilherme valeu! Deu certo! :)

Comment: por nada! favor votar na resposta (flecha) e marcar (check) que ela resolveu o seu problema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a instalação do pacote `caret` foi feita com sucesso, antes de rodar a função `preProcess`, você precisa chamar o pacote `caret`, via `library(caret)`.

A instalação é feita apenas uma vez, enquanto que chamar a função via `library` deve ser feita após iniciar o R.